# User missing from login greeter, despite `SystemAccount=false` in /var/lib/AccountServices/users file

Tags: login

I seem to be ailed with a problem most people consider a solution: my user is hidden from the login greeter. 
I've been frustrated by the login system for quite a while, there doesn't seem to be clear configuration or possible configuration of the login greeter user list settings.

My setup is pretty simple, Debian Stable (Stretch), add libpam-krb5 and configure it to point at the krb5-kdc server. gdm3 as the greeter, though I'm open to suggestions I am pretty unhappy with login greeters across the board. Regular old linux account. `su <user>` works, entering the user name and password into the login greeter works, just not an option to select (which I wouldn't mind if the "other users" dialog was keyboard accessible)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AccountServices was assuming the user was disabled because of the `:!:` portion of /etc/shadow, I edited that to `:*:` by hand and the user shows up. I am confused because previously I was having issues with all passwords working to login to a krb5 user, and I got the impression flipping the shadow flag from * to ! is what kept the password field working correctly. If anyone would like to post some details on how to administer pam such that krb5 credentials are the only option unless an administer specifically creates a local password for a user I would be all ears.